# Scale a view to another view's size using ValueAnimator

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to resize a view to fit another view's size using a ValueAnimator. I'm using it instead of an Animation because I need the view to be clickable afterwards.

```
private Animator getHeightScaleAnimator(View target) {
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams thisParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams targetParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) target.getLayoutParams();

    int currentHeight = thisParams.height;
    int desiredHeight = targetParams.height;

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(currentHeight, desiredHeight);
    animator.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
        int newInt = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        thisParams.width = newInt;
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    });
    return animator;
}
```

The above code shows a method in which I try to increase the view's height to the desired view's height, and I have the same method for the width, but with width instead of height.

The desired behaviour was the view to increase it's size until it's as big as the target view, but for some odd reason, the view **moves** instead of resizing.

The implementing class is an extension of ImageView, but no method from ImageView as changed.

---

**What can I possibly do to increase a view's size up to another view's size in an animated fashion?**

Comment: are you aware of [Scenes and Transitions](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html)? you can use `android.support.transition` to support older devices

Comment: I gave it a look, but don't think that helps me

Comment: Or I didn't understand it

Comment: I want to grow a view to be as big as another view, the scenes and transitions didn't look helpful to me

Comment: Using a ChangeBounds transition works even worse. Now the full image is revealed, but it slowly 'scans' the rest of the image.

Comment: did you try the samples i posted? are they working fine? if so, try to follow them, i cannot tell anything without seeing any of your code

Comment: I did. I tried using a `Transition t = new Changebounds(); TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parent, t); //Change the width`

Comment: And it came out in a buggier way

Comment: `"Now the full image is revealed"`, is it ImageView? if so, did you try `android.transition.ChangeImageTransform`? the docs say:  *This Transition captures an ImageView's matrix before and after the scene change and animates it during the transition.

In combination with ChangeBounds, ChangeImageTransform allows ImageViews that change size, shape, or ImageView.ScaleType to animate contents smoothly.*

Comment: Yes, as my question, it is an ImageView I'll check on ChangeImageTransform

Comment: ChangeImageTransform works, do you know how to use it in API < 19?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html ^F `Note:`

Comment: @Kerooker, [TransitionEverywhere](https://github.com/andkulikov/Transitions-Everywhere) will backport it to API 14.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using `ConstraintLayout`. Most possibly you have applied such constraints that result in such a behavior. Try with other parent `ViewGroup`, that should work. Also share your layout file.

Comment: I'm going to guess that your view is being resized properly but the content is not. Consider that you need to use fitXY in order for the content to scale the way you want it to (you also become responsible for making sure you scale the view in a way that the aspect ratio is perserved).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Just add following method in your code.**

```
private Animator getViewScaleAnimator(View from, final View target) {
        // height resize animation
        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        int desiredHeight = from.getHeight();
        int currentHeight = target.getHeight();
        ValueAnimator heightAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(currentHeight, desiredHeight);
        heightAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) target.getLayoutParams();
                params.height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                target.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        });
        animatorSet.play(heightAnimator);

        // width resize animation
        int desiredWidth = from.getWidth();
        int currentWidth = target.getWidth();
        ValueAnimator widthAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(currentWidth, desiredWidth);
        widthAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) target.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                target.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        });
        animatorSet.play(widthAnimator);
        return animatorSet;
    }
```

**And call it on any event.( eg. click )**

```
getViewScaleAnimator(fromView, targetView).setDuration(1000).start();
```

**Here is an output.**

[image]

Comment: How to do the same behavior when target view is in the center?

Comment: @musooff then you may need to use property animator instead value animator.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet but instead of the ValueAnimator you could try to use a ScaleAnimation:

```
float scaleY = (float) currentHeight / (float) desiredHeight;
curView.animate().scaleY(scaleY);
```

Of course you need to do the same with the width if it is working because with `scaleY`you are only scaling up the height.

Additionally you can call `.setDuration(1000)` if you want to change the animation duration.